# Having trouble with Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am having trouble with Parse that in a list view item, when I click and open another Activity it calls data from Parse.

But as soon as I click back and then, click second list view item which also calls the data. then the app crashes. The same problem occurs with the action bar item also.

Is there any way that the app call data from parse and will not get closed as I click for another call?

Comment: no one will help unless you show your code

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: you should also post your error log and where exactly the crash happens